# is Writer permission for Mssql user is enough to make backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

i have many user for sql server Database and i need to know if the backupOperator right is included in one of the general roles (reader, writer, admin) or should i grant the specific user and give him this right... ?

Comment: what is a _manz user_?

Comment: many users* sorry (mistyping)

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice would be to either create a role for users that require backup privileges or simply assign the user the backup operator role. 
Assigning the user the Admin privilege would give them too much power.
The reader and writer privileges do not include the db backup privilege.